# Como hago para sacar este espacio en blanco que me aparece del lado derecho de el header?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hola, tengo en el header ese espacio blanco(el que señale en la imagen) y no se como sacarlo. Ya probe con el padding, el margin y todo eso, pero aun asi no lo logro sacar. Soy nueva en todo esto.
[image: codigo html]
[image: codigo css]

Comment: Hola y bienvenida. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código como texto en lugar de usar screenshots. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas lo que te comento.

Answer (score 0):

Natalia.

creo que el problema está en `max-width` por que esos pixeles limitan el ancho que puede tener tu header, intenta con: `max-width: 100%;` si notas que es mucho header pones 90%  me comentas si te funcionó :)

Answer (score 0):

La `class= “container”` de bootstrap tiene un límite de ancho por defecto.
Para solucionarlo deberías cambiar la `class=“container”` por `class=“container-fluid`. Esto hará que ocupe todo el ancho de pantalla.
También estaría bien que le quitaras el `max-width` del CSS, si no en algunos dispositivos podría no llenar todo el ancho